# Exclude appsettings.json file from GitHub Repo

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have an existing Visual Studio project file (`appsettings.json`) that contains sensitive data that I do not want to publish to GitHub.

A repository is not currently created but I would like to create one without including the `appsettings.json` file.

I know that I can use the `.gitignore` file to exclude files after the initial push, but at this point the sensitive file would already have been pushed.

Moving forward, I can create the repository from the start of the project, but how should this be handled for an existing project without a repository?

Comment: Just don't include the file in the initial commit.

Comment: How can I do this in VS?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I never use VS for git, as I prefer TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I can use the `.gitignore` file to exclude files after the initial push

Actually, you can use it *before* the initial push, even before the initial add to the index.

Simply create in VSCode a `.gitignore` at the root folder of your project, with as a content:

```
/.vscode/appsettings.json
```

(assuming this setting file was created automatically in the `.vscode/` folder of your VSCode workspace for this project)

Then add and commit: you won't see that file in your first commit, than you can then push.

Comment: Thank you!  I added the .gitignore file manually to the root and then published to a new repo.  The appsettings.json file was ignored in github.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio,

- Goto the solution explorer
- Right click the file you want to git ignore
- Goto "Git"
- Then select "Ignore and untrack item"

I did the above to my appsettings.json and this is the entry i found in the .gitignore at the end of the file.

> /MyProject.WebApi/appsettings.json

Here, "MyProject.WebApi" is inside the main directory.